# Facebook messenger - Is it possible to disable a payload button in a Generic Template?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to build a chatbot in FB messenger.  One point in my flow displays a confirmation-style view where the user chooses to confirm whether they want to proceed.  I'm using the "Generic Template" and two post back buttons to achieve this, which gives the UI I'm looking for.

The issue I have is that the buttons continue to be visible for the rest of the conversation.  I can obviously code to prevent a second call, but it would be nice to lose the options once one has been selected.

Is there any way I can do this?  The best I can find is to replace the post backs with "quick replies", but these don't look good and seem to be a bit buggy when used on a browser (the buttons appeared *on top* of my template, not below them).

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? I am looking for exactly the same thing. I would use quick replies, but they don't allow you to put a url for a webview in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you can't edit previous message anyway.